# How to have a RulesChecker add an error to an associated Model?

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my ContentsTable, I add an application rule like this, making sure at least one ImageEntity is added to the ContentEntity when saving:

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules) {
    $rules
        ->add(function($entity, $options) {
            return $entity->get('type') !== 'gallery' || count($entity->images) > 0;
        }, 'validDate', [
            'errorField' => 'images.0.image',
            'message' => 'Lade mindestens ein Bild hoch!'
        ]);

    return $rules;
}
```

The rule is applied, since the `save()` fails, but I would have expected the defined error message to appear on this form input in `Contents/edit.ctp`:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('images.0.image', [
    'label' => 'Neues Bild (optional)',
    'type' => 'file',
    'required' => false
]); ?>
```

It is, however, not added at all.

**How can I set the `errorField` option to add the error to this field?**

Comment: Disregarding your image being optional and mandatory at the same time, have you added a unique validator on this field? Then the rules message will not be displayed.

Comment: No, I have no Validation on the ImageTable itself. The image inputs are optional because there are multiple of them (images.0.image, image.1.image, images.2.image and so on). None of them are required, but I still need to check to make sure there is at least one image on saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying paths isn't possible, also in the entity context the errors are expected to be present on an actual entity object, so even if it were possible to specifiy a path, there would be no entity to set the error on.

You could always modify the entity in the rule yourself, however I'm not overly convinced that this is such a good idea. Anyways, what you'd have to do, is to fill the `images` property with a list that contains one entity with the proper error on the `image` field, something along the lines of:

```
->add(function($entity, $options) {
    if ($entity->get('type') !== 'gallery' || count($entity->images) > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    $image = $this->Images->newEntity();
    $image->errors('image', 'Lade mindestens ein Bild hoch!');

    $entity->set('images', [
        $image
    ]);

    return false;
});
```

Another option, which to me feels a little cleaner, would be to set the error for the `images` property, and evaluate it manually in the form, ie something like:

```
->add(
    function($entity, $options) {
        return $entity->get('type') !== 'gallery' || count($entity->images) > 0;
    },
    'imageCount',
    [
        'errorField' => 'images',
        'message' => 'Lade mindestens ein Bild hoch!'
    ]
);
```

```
if ($this->Form->isFieldError('images')) {
    echo $this->Form->error('images');
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Validation > Using Validation as Application Rules](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#using-validation-as-application-rules)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Displaying and Checking Errors](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#displaying-and-checking-errors)**

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know I could actually modify the entity in the Rule. Anyway, I went with option 2, works pretty well and I can even position the error right above all the Image inputs.